# How to track the age of a case spent in different status value?

Tags: reporting, status

I've to create a report on the case object. I've to display how much time a case has spent in a particular status. I've around 6 status values such as Initiated, Waiting for Approval, On Hold, Closed etc., I want to determine how much time a case has spent in each of the status values?

For ex: I have a case 0010. The case age is 10 days, it is in Waiting approval stage for 4 days. I want to track the number of days it has spent in the current status. I tried case life-cycle report but that's not what I'm actually I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the stage changes create an activity with a date/time stamp. Stamp the previous task with the new date/time when the new activity is created.

This should get you close:

```
public void createStatusChangeEvents(Map<Id, Case> updatedCases, Map<Id, Case> oldCases) {
    List<Event> newEvents = new List<Event>();
    List<Event> lastEvents = new List<Event>();

    // Get the most recent activity per case
    updatedCases = new Map<Id, Case>([
        SELECT Id, (
            SELECT Id
            FROM Events
            WHERE Type = 'Status Change'
            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
        FROM Case
        WHERE Id IN :updatedCases
    ]);

    for (Case c : updatesCases.values()) {
        // If the status changes
        if (c.Status != oldCases.get(c.Id).Status) {
            // Create a new event
            newEvents.add(new Event(
                StartTime = system.now(),
                WhatId = c.Id,
                CustomStatusTrackingField__c = c.Status
            ));

            // If the case already has an event
            if (c.Events != null && !c.Events.isEmpty()) {
                // Update the existing event
                c.Events[0].EndTime = system.now()
                lastEvents.add(c.Events[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    insert newEvents;
    update oldEvents;
}
```

last you can create a formula field on event to track the days in that status:

```
IF(ISBLANK(EndDate), TODAY()-StartDate, EndDate - StartDate)
```

### Notes:

- The field names I used may not be correct
- I used event because it already has start/end date fields but you can
  use task if you want to add custom fields or a custom object
  altogether, if your org has them a big object would be great for this
  purpose

Comment: `if (!newEvents.isEmpty()) {` is not necessary any longer.

Comment: Oh? Why is that?

Comment: A DML on an empty list no longer count towards governor limits, it's a no-op. Technically, checking if the list is empty first has worse performance than not (it's only a few ms, though, nothing major).

Comment: I for some reason thought it would throw an exception but if that's not the case this is great, reduces the load on my little fingers that much more.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a formula field that's a little more complete. Added some comments and added a type filter to the event query